# SNORT Conf File MACOS

Tags: macos, snort

I installed SNORT using `brew install snort` . However, there is no configuration file installed (snort.conf). Is this normal? How do I manage rules then?

Also, when I run SNORT, there is the error `WARNING: No preprocessors configured for policy 0.`

It is probably linked to the configuration file. Any advice regarding this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not familiar with MacOS, but [Snort typically bundles a configuration file in its tarball](https://www.snort.org/configurations).